# ArgumentException was unhandled while parsing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing, argumentexception

**My Goal:** I want to parse XML file for "REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER" which is **987654** and display it in a textbox. My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This file was generated. -->
<ModificationMap>
<replace>
<!-- Asset Type -->
<text symbol="__HIS_NAME__">Example</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_Example1__">My Program</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_Example2__">EG</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_Example3__">XMLPARSING</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_Example4__">Not Applicable</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_ExampleINTERVAL__">300</text>
</replace>
<replace>
<!-- HIS profile -->
<text symbol="__EG_HIS_NAME__">EG_NotConfigured</text>
<text symbol="__EG_HIS_PASSWORD__">password</text>
<text symbol="__EG_HIS_ExampleINTERVAL__">300</text>
<text symbol="__EG_SERIALNUMBER__">666</text>
</replace>
<replace>
<!-- Changed Number and ID -->
<text symbol="__Example_SERIALNUMBER__">123456789</text>
<text symbol="__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__">987654</text>
<text symbol="__HER_ExampleINTERVAL__">300</text>
<text symbol="__HER_LEVEL__">WARN</text>
<text symbol="__Example_VERSION__">20</text>
<text symbol="__Example_THIRDPARTYVERSION__">20</text>
<!-- Asset Profile -->
<text symbol="__HIS_MEMBERNAME__">EG_NotConfigured</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_FRIENDLYNAME__">XMLProgram</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_DESCRIPTION__">testprogram</text>
</replace>
<replace>
<!-- Software director -->
<text symbol="__ADMINUSERNAME__">admin</text>
<text symbol="__ADMINPASSWORD__">password</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_PORT__">0000</text>
<text symbol="__HIS_SCHEME__">http</text>
</replace>
<replace>
<!-- Misc settings -->
<text symbol="__LOG_LEVEL__">ERROR</text>
</replace>
</ModificationMap>
```

**My Code:**

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dict2 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\DEMO.xml")
        .Descendants("text")
        .ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("symbol").Value, 
        f => f.Value);
    textBox7.Text = dict2["__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__"];
}
```

**I am getting an Error:**

> ArgumentException was unhandled. An item with the same key has already
>   been added.

Please can you help me rectify the problem? Thanks for your help! I am new to c#. :)

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question and then ask exactly the same thing again?

Comment: @JonSkeet The XML File was wrong. I apologize for that. I tried with this new XML file. Still getting the same error: ArgumentException was unhandled. An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: You should have edited the previous question and replied to my comment in that question then...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your suggestion. I apologize. This won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need whole document parsed to `Dictionary<string, string>` to get the value you need. Try following:

```
var query = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\DEMO.xml")
    .Root.Elements("replace").Elements("text")
    .Where(f => (string)f.Attribute("symbol") == "__REGISTRATION_CATALOGNUMBER__")
    .Select(f => (string)f);
textBox7.Text = query.FirstOrDefault();
```